# Attribute manipulation on shapefile

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-desktop, fme-form

I have a shapefile which contains landuse types. The Landuse types are written in a field called "Type" and contain also the area in m² and a landuse code. Some polygons contain more than one landuse type separated with a tab

An example or such a field would be

(43001-1200) Brachland 1185 m²
(43002-1300) Laub- und Nadelholz 14 m²

What I would like to do is make a list of the landuse types that interest me, and then search the field for these types. If the word is contained within the field, that polygon should be selected.

I then need to remove the code and the area leaving just the Landuse type. IE int he above example the resulting polygon would simply have Brachland, Laub- und Nadelholz in the field.

I have ArcGIS (Editor License) and FME Desktop. Does anyone have an idea which approach would work best?

Thanks for any replies,

Rob

Comment: Use FME and the AttributeSplitter http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/AttributeSplitter

Answer (score 1):

[Select by Attribute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000021000000) using the [LIKE](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002t000000) operator.

This is the little script I use for selecting multiple terms in the Python window:

```
import string

Search_Field = "Field Name Here"
Layer = "Layer Name Here"
Input_Terms = "Term1, Term2, Term3, etc"

split_terms = Input_Terms.split(',')
terms = [s.strip() for s in split_terms]

where = ""
for term in terms:
    where += "UPPER(\"" + Search_Field + "\") LIKE '%" + term.upper() + "%' OR "
where = where[:-4]

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Layer, "NEW_SELECTION", where)
```